# What's the encoding in which the file is saved when I use open(filename) in Python or fopen(filename) in C?

Tags: python, encoding, python-2.7, file-encodings

Runtime Environment: Python 2.7, Windows 7

NOTE:I am talking about the encoding of the file generated by the PYTHON source code(NOT talking about the PYTHON source file's encoding), the encoding declared at the top of the PYTHON source file DID agree with the encoding in which the PYTHON source file was saved.

When there are no non-ascii characters in the string(`content = 'abc'`), the file(`file.txt`, NOT the PYTHON source file) is saved in ANSI encoding after `fp.close()`, the PYTHON file's(and it is saved in ANSI encoding format) content is as below:

```
## Author: melo
## Email:prevision@imsrch.tk
## Date: 2012/10/12
import os

def write_file(filepath, mode, content):
    try:
        fp = open(filepath, mode)
        try:
            print 'file encoding:', fp.encoding
            print 'file mode:', fp.mode
            print 'file closed?', fp.closed
            fp.write(content)
        finally:
            fp.close()
            print 'file closed?', fp.closed
    except IOError, e:
        print e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file.txt')
    content = 'abc'
    write_file(filepath, 'wb', content)
```

but when there are some non-ascii characters in the string(`content = 'abc莹'`), the file(`file.txt`) will be saved in UTF-8 encoding after `fp.close()`, although I declared the encoding at the top of the PYTHON source file(not `file.txt`) with `#encoding=gbk`. At this time, the PYTHON source file's content is as below:

```
# -*- encoding: gbk -*-
## Author: melo
## Email:prevision@imsrch.tk
## Date: 2012/10/12
import os

def write_file(filepath, mode, content):
    try:
        fp = open(filepath, mode)
        try:
            print 'file encoding:', fp.encoding
            print 'file mode:', fp.mode
            print 'file closed?', fp.closed
            fp.write(content)
        finally:
            fp.close()
            print 'file closed?', fp.closed
    except IOError, e:
        print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file.txt')
    content = 'abc莹'
    write_file(filepath, 'wb', content)
```

Is there any proof that it behaves like this?

Comment: What makes you say it is "saved" in UTF8?

Comment: @eakron `file.txt` is saved in UTF-8 encoding format after `fp.close()`, the file's encoding. I am not sure if I made it clear.

Comment: note: the fact that `'莹'` is displayed correctly means that your file is not in gbk unless copy-paste uses Unicode. `u'\u83b9'` Unicode character is `'\xd3\xa8'` two bytes as gbk and `'\xe8\x8e\xb9'` three bytes as utf-8. try `print repr(content)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am talking about the encoding of the file generated by the PYTHON source code(NOT talking about the PYTHON source file's encoding), the encoding declared at the top of the PYTHON source file DID agree with the encoding in which the PYTHON source file was saved.

Comment: `content` is a byte string which contains ... bytes. Which bytes it contains is defined by the Python source encoding because you use a Python string literal to create it. Then you use 'wb' mode to write these bytes as is to disk. Therefore the `file.txt` file encoding is defined by the Python source file encoding. To avoid that use Unicode strings inside your script and use `codecs` module to save these string to a file with desired encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file is saved in the encoding *you* save it in.  A source file is saved in the encoding *you* save it in.  They don't have to be the same, they just should be *declared*.

Per your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12969897/235698), I assume you are using Notepad++ and when you open `file.txt` you find that Notepad++ thinks the file is encoded in `UTF-8 without BOM`.  This is an incorrect *guess* by Notepad++.  Select the Chinese GB2312 character set and the file will display properly.

Unless given a hint by a byte order mark (BOM) or some other metadata or told by the user, programs have no idea what encoding a file is in.

A correct Python program would do these things:

1. Declare the encoding of the source file if non-ASCII characters are used in the source file.
2. Use Unicode strings for all text.
3. Encode the Unicode strings when output to a binary stream such as a file.
4. Decode incoming text data to Unicode when read from a binary stream.
5. (optional) Use an encoding with a byte-order mark so editors know the file encoding.

Example:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import codecs
with codecs.open('file.txt','wb',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    f.write(u'abc莹')
```

You should now see in Notepad++ that `file.txt` is detected as encoded as 'UTF-8' (with BOM) and display the file properly.

Note that you can save the file in 'ANSI' (GBK on your system) if you declare the encoding as `gbk` and it will still work because Unicode strings were used.

Actually, your system probably is code page 936 (`cp936`) instead of GBK.  They aren't precisely the same.  Better to use a Unicode encoding like UTF-8 or UTF-16 which can represent all Unicode characters accurately.

Comment: +1 for 1-4 but 5 is questionable (instead you could use editors that understand the encoding declaration or just prefer utf-8 for source code encoding (it is default on Python 3)).

Comment: 5 was optional just for people with your opinion :).  `file.txt` doesn't have an encoding declaration.  Only the source file does.  I would love for the world to use UTF-8 for all text files but alas that is not the case.

Comment: I'm sorry for my crappy English, I have carefully re-edit my problem and hope I have made it clear.

Comment: What's the difference between `codecs.open('file.txt','wb',encoding='utf-8-sig')` and `codecs.open('file.txt','wb',encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: It writes the file with a UTF-8-encoded byte order mark character as an encoding signature. On reading, the `utf-8-sig` codec will automatically detect and remove the extra character. On Windows, where locale-encoded (ANSI) files are common, it helps some editors such as Notepad detect that the file is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- encoding: gbk -*-
```

at the top of your PYTHON file, indicates the encoding of the PYTHON file. to work with codecs 
use the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) module.

you need this: [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open)

Comment: I know this module works, but I just want to figure it out that why it behaves like this if I do not use `codecs` module.